# Работа с кардридером

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-7

Добрый день!

Подскажите, плиз. Кто писал проекты на делфи по работе с кардридером, чтобы считывать и записывать чипованые пластиковые  карточки?

Это нужно не для взлома и уж тем более не для кражи персональной информации. Карточки будут служить ключом авторизации. В Интернете есть проект uFRCoder, в котором показывались чтение, запись и форматирование карты. Может, есть у кого компоненты либо исходники или хотя бы ссылки для ознакомления?

Благодарю за внимание!

**Обновление**

Модель Realtek USB smart Card Reader 
ID USB\Vid_0bda&Pid_0165&Rev_6123

Comment: Нужно как минимум модель устройства, с которым Вы работаете.

В каждом устройстве свой картридер и свои API для работы с ними.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле я бы не согласился с комментариями. Все намного проще, сам занят подобной темой. В винде есть библиотека winscard.dll. Эта волшебная библиотека реализует протокол PC/SC - говоря проще, протокол обмена данными между компом (PC) - смарт картой (SC). У протокола есть огромный плюс, ему приливать, какой ты картридер используешь. И еще этот протокол открытый!!! Спасибо богам! ) Я даже находил примеры как раз на delphi. Суть проста - статический вызов процедур из этой dll. А винда сделает за тебя всю черную работу.

**Обновление**

Тем более если они просто ключ авторизации, тебе нужно, например, только получать серийник карточки, а дальше, например, по нему определять владельца и уровень его доступа.

**Обновление**

Вот описание протокола правда примеры на С++. http://forum.vingrad.ru/articles/topic-192183/kw-pcsc.html Сейчас поищу, напишу еще порядок работы.

Вот порядок примерный работы.

1. Инициализация ридера.
2. Инициализация карты.
3. Открытия карты для чтения (или для чтения и записи). Каждый пункт вызов функции из dll,  или можешь пользоваться скачанным pas. Я бы сам написал. Для затравки советую покапать в сторону статичекого вызова функции/процедуры из dll.

Я сейчас просто парально работаю над похожей проблемой, если я выложу результаты на своей сайте myshinobi.ru. Там есть мое мылко, если что, пиши.

Comment: "чтобы считывать и записывать чипованые пластиковые карточки"

А эта dll в винде для работы с картридером, каким его знает большинство пользователей, для работы с  SD, MMC, MicroSD, Memory Stick Micro, Memory Stick Duo, Compact Flash, xD, MiniSD и прочим.

Подобная тема основная часть моей работы... и к каждому отдельному устройству идёт Dll от производителя для работы с ним, если мы говорим о "чипованных пластиковых картах".

Comment: Благодарю за отклики! 
Задача состоит в том чтобы считывать чипованые пластиковые карточки. 
Данная winscard.dll подходит ли для данной задачи? Вы как-то упомянули что находили примеры, не поделитесь ли ссылкой или своим опытом. Не имею большого опыта работать с dll файлами. 
 
Уважаемый Isaev, подскажите пожалуйста, DLL искать в драйвере на компакт диске, или нужно запрашивать у производителя. Может вам уже попадался такой кардреадер (модель Realtek USB smart Card Reader) и у вас уже иметься нужная DLL. Можете поделиться опытом?
Благодарю всех за активное участие!

Comment: Нашел один файл 

http://wmkey-project.googlecode.com/svn-history/r38/trunk   /BHO_IE_PlugIn/src/WinSCard.pas

Сохранил его WinSCard.pas, подключил к проекту, после нашел целый список функций, начинающихся на SCard........... и т.д.  
Но так и не понял, как эти функции использовать...  
Подскажите, плиз, в верном направлении "копаю"?

Comment: Да ты в правильном направлении копаешь..,Сейчас объясню

Comment: Я накидал статью, правда, там упор на полисы омс. Может, слышал электронные карты с чипом. Там и ссылки есть, и мои рассуждения, и даже исходники, правда, на C++, но можно общую схему проследить. http://myshinobi.ru/rabota-s-e-lektronny-mi-polisami-oms-smart-kartami-chast-pervaya/

Answer (score 0):

[@p_redator](/users/3609/p_redator), в моих случаях всегда производитель вместе с устройством поставлял, как на компакте, так и у себя на сайте... И часто описание работы с устройством так же описано производителем